# $watch not firing on data change

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a watch setup against the model of a ui-select2 dropdown (from ui-bootstrap).  The watch fires on load but not on data changes and I can't figure out why.

It isn't the usual problem of not $apply'ing the model change or not using the third parameter for equality comparison (at least from my code).

What do I need to do to get it to fire?

[Here is a plunk demonstrating the issue.](http://plnkr.co/edit/xsclxVpkOgpIKwSK4S1d?p=preview)

Comment: I had a $watch not firing but turns out I had an ng-if that was creating a new scope, so I needed to put ng-model="$parent.myModal", since I was actually watching the parents myModal..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I fixed some stuff.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5Zaln7QT2gETVcGiMdoW?p=preview

The JS

```
var myMod = angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("MainController",  function($scope){
  $scope.myModel = {selectedId:null};
}).controller("DetailController",function($scope){
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4];

  $scope.watchHitCount = 0;
  $scope.$watch('myModel.selectedId', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal + " " + oldVal);
    $scope.watchHitCount++;
  },true);
});
```

The index.html

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <ng-include src="'detail.html'" ng-controller="DetailController"></ng-include>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The detail.html

```
<pre>watch hit: {{watchHitCount}}</pre>
<pre>selected value: {{myModel.selectedId}}</pre>
<select ng-model="myModel.selectedId" ui-select2="">
  <option></option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

It was complaining about not finding the controller so I set it up the way I normally would with a named ng-app and a module declared that has controllers defined on it.

**I also added an object to hold the value in your model.**  It is bad practice to use the $scope object as your model, instead your scope should refer to an object that is your model.

Comment: So this worked previously for me without using an object... At some point this broke without me making direct changes to the filters. I may have added some rootscope variables elsewhere and some watchers elsewhere in the app template components.. Is there a common reason why I should be using objects rather than just variables, like in this solution?

Comment: @shaunhusain can you please explain why variable wont worked any object worked

Comment: @parshuram if you look up mtv best practices angular you'll get a video from misko around 30 min in he explains this a bit.

Answer (score 125):

Try passing `true` as a 3rd argument to `.$watch()`

[`$rootScope.Scope` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)
```

> objectEquality(optional) – {boolean=} – Compare object for equality rather than for reference.

Answer (score 12):

There are a simple fix for that, to use watch with complex object instead of simple variable

For example (DON"T USE)

```
$scope.selectedType=1;//default
$scope.$watch(
            function () {
                return $scope.selectedType;
            },
            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
                    $scope.DoWork();
                }
            },
            true);
```

But Use below

```
$scope.selecteditem={selectedType:1};
$scope.$watch(
            function () {
                return $scope.selecteditem.selectedType;
            },
            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
                    $scope.DoWork();
                }
            },
            true);
```

note that "slectedTypes" in the second example located inside object, not just scope variable. this will work even in old Angular versions.

Comment: I think my answer could work, but "@Casey Flynn" 's answer is more accurate and precise . http://stackoverflow.com/a/17795221/471499

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the controller-as approach some reading might suggest a syntax like this:

```
var myController = {
    myValue: 1
};
$scope.$watch('$ctrl.myValue', function () {
    ...
}, true);
```

Instead just wrap the field in a function like this:

```
var myController = {
    myValue: 1
};
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return myController.myValue;
}, function () {
    ...
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me:

```
  var ctrl = this;

  this.$onInit = function () {
    console.log("id " + ctrl.event.id);
  };
```

from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#!