# button toggle not working with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to simply change the button text with a toggle but I'm failing to do so I don't know why.The button only shows 'ver fotos' and doesnt change to my 2nd option. Maybe i can't put two ng-click like that? This is my code:

```js
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('perfilCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', "detailService",// The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams, detailService) {
$scope.detalhes=detailService.data;
$scope.goEsconder = false;
$scope.toggle = true;
$scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
$scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Ver fotos' : 'Ver características';
   })

}])
```

```html
<ion-view id="page4">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="backg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h3 class="name">{{detalhes[0]}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="descricao">{{detalhes[2]}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center" ui-sref="contacto"><button class="button b2">
                Contactar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center"><button class="button b3" ng-click="goEsconder = !goEsconder; toggle = !toggle">
                {{toggleText}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Can you try `console.log($scope.toggle)` inside the `$watch`

Comment: It gives back "true"

Comment: My bet is this is nested in a child scope. Provide a demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object so that child scopes will use inheritance. There is no inheritance on primitives in javascript.

So what happens is you are only changing the primitive in the child scope and that change is hidden from the parent so the watch won't fire

```
  $scope.myModel = { toggle: true };
  $scope.$watch('myModel.toggle', function(nVal, oVal) {
    $scope.toggleText = $scope.myModel.toggle ? 'Ver fotos' : 'Ver características';
  });
```

HTML

```
<button class="button b3" ng-click="myModel.toggle = !myModel.toggle">
  {{toggleText}}
</button>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OddO3jBGpoyNadeGGqC8?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Alternatively if you had used a function to do the boolean toggle in controller it would have also worked. Angular internal scope watches would have updated the child scope

Answer (score 0):

I believe it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10594/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.toggleText = 'click me'
    $scope.toggle = true
    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
        $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Ver fotos' : 'Ver características';
    })
}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="button b3" ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not working here, im testing it on ionic lab. maybe its cause of the child scope thing?

Comment: @MárioSouto yes very high probability it is a child scope nesting issue as there are lots of directives that create child scope but you haven't shown enough context for anyone to know for sure

Comment: Maybe add more code surrounding the `<div class="col text-center">`.

Comment: @MartinGottweis just edited my code, does that help?

Comment: Ehm, where is the `perfilCtrl` controller?

Comment: @MartinGottweis .state('perfil', {
    url: '/page4',
    templateUrl: 'templates/perfil.html',
    controller: 'perfilCtrl'
  })

Comment: `ion-content` creates it's own scope. Maybe you can create a new `toggler` directive and use it on the button. @charlietfl also suggested the object thing that will make the toggle accessible even if it's defined in parent scope.

Answer (score -1):

Change your watcher to use the `true` parameter, this way:

```
$scope.$watch('toggle', function(toggle){
   $scope.toggleText = toggle ? 'Ver fotos' : 'Ver características';
}, true)
```

this will make your code work because watchers doesn't work natively on boolean values (because boolean values  are passed by value on javascript: for your watcher `toggle` is always true )

Specifying the true parameter, however, will change your watcher to a *deep watcher*, being so able to catch *value changes* and not only *references changes*.

Comment: It still doesnt toggle between the two :\

Comment: include the variable as parameter too, like shown in my answer.

Comment: This is nonsense. Watch works fine on a primitive. OP's code works when not nested in a child scope

Comment: False. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17795221/1306679 and the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

"when objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function"

Comment: that is about objects. You are misinterpreting what you are reading. Also i posted a link in comments showing that it works